# Why don't I get exception when invalid XML is validated with Schema?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxparser

Here is XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="products">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="product" type="ProductType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="ProductType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" />
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

XML file that is validated for conformance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<products>
  <product>
    <invalid_tag>32342</invalid_tag>
    <name>Some name</name>
    <price>3.89</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

Java code that works with XML and should test conformance:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(xmlSchema)));
parser = factory.newSAXParser();
ProductsSaxHandler handler = new ProductsSaxHandler();
parser.parse(new File(xmlFile), handler);
```

But I don't get any exception. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are using custom `ProductsSaxHandler`.

You did not provide code for it, but most likely it does not throw an exception when one of the notification methods of `ErrorHandler` interface is called.

Make sure you override `error`, `fatalError` and `warning` methods of `ProductSaxHandler` to throw an exception.

Comment: I haven't implemented those methods in handler.